# TA-Lib's strange behaviour on limited dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, ta-lib

this TA-Lib code

```
df = pd.read_csv('RTS-MINUTES15.csv', header=None, 
    names=['index', 'OPEN', 'HIGH', 'LOW', 'CLOSE', 'VOL'], 
    index_col=0, skiprows = 1, nrows = 15)    

df['HAMMER'] = talib.CDLHAMMER(df['OPEN'], df['HIGH'], df['LOW'], df['CLOSE'])
print(df)
```

gives

```
                         OPEN      HIGH       LOW     CLOSE    VOL  HAMMER
index
2020-10-23 10:00:00  115090.0  115180.0  114720.0  114890.0  25100       0
2020-10-23 10:15:00  114890.0  115140.0  114600.0  115120.0  20920       0
2020-10-23 10:30:00  115120.0  115690.0  115120.0  115670.0  30587       0
2020-10-23 10:45:00  115670.0  115750.0  115510.0  115690.0  16208       0
2020-10-23 11:00:00  115700.0  115960.0  115540.0  115950.0  22705       0
2020-10-23 11:15:00  115950.0  116270.0  115900.0  116250.0  24552       0
2020-10-23 11:30:00  116250.0  116350.0  116080.0  116240.0  14682       0
2020-10-23 11:45:00  116240.0  116290.0  115960.0  116030.0  10856       0
2020-10-23 12:00:00  116030.0  116120.0  115950.0  116080.0   5965       0
2020-10-23 12:15:00  116070.0  116420.0  116060.0  116230.0  12657       0
2020-10-23 12:30:00  116230.0  116340.0  116160.0  116170.0   6673       0
2020-10-23 12:45:00  116170.0  116270.0  116120.0  116190.0   6299       0
2020-10-23 13:00:00  116200.0  116390.0  116190.0  116220.0   9088       0
**2020-10-23 13:15:00  116240.0  116260.0  116070.0  116180.0   8626     100**
2020-10-23 13:30:00  116180.0  116240.0  116060.0  116110.0   5722       0
```

Code works fine, HAMMER = 100 in row "2020-10-23 13:15:00"

But if I do "skiprows=5" instead of "skiprows=1" then TA-Lib couldn't find the HAMMER:

```
df = pd.read_csv('RTS-MINUTES15.csv', header=None, 
    names=['index', 'OPEN', 'HIGH', 'LOW', 'CLOSE', 'VOL'], 
    index_col=0, skiprows = 5, nrows = 15)
```

result

```
                         OPEN      HIGH       LOW     CLOSE    VOL  HAMMER
index
2020-10-23 11:00:00  115700.0  115960.0  115540.0  115950.0  22705       0
2020-10-23 11:15:00  115950.0  116270.0  115900.0  116250.0  24552       0
2020-10-23 11:30:00  116250.0  116350.0  116080.0  116240.0  14682       0
2020-10-23 11:45:00  116240.0  116290.0  115960.0  116030.0  10856       0
2020-10-23 12:00:00  116030.0  116120.0  115950.0  116080.0   5965       0
2020-10-23 12:15:00  116070.0  116420.0  116060.0  116230.0  12657       0
2020-10-23 12:30:00  116230.0  116340.0  116160.0  116170.0   6673       0
2020-10-23 12:45:00  116170.0  116270.0  116120.0  116190.0   6299       0
2020-10-23 13:00:00  116200.0  116390.0  116190.0  116220.0   9088       0
**2020-10-23 13:15:00  116240.0  116260.0  116070.0  116180.0   8626       0**
2020-10-23 13:30:00  116180.0  116240.0  116060.0  116110.0   5722       0
2020-10-23 13:45:00  116110.0  116160.0  116000.0  116070.0   7500       0
2020-10-23 14:00:00  116050.0  116150.0  115990.0  116040.0   3929       0
2020-10-23 14:15:00  116030.0  116040.0  115700.0  115780.0  14745       0
2020-10-23 14:30:00  115780.0  116090.0  115750.0  116080.0  10776       0
```

Experimentally I found that it finds the HAMMER if "skiprows" is between 1-4

Why?

P.S. RAW data is [here](https://pastebin.com/QnWX6z3t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because CDLHAMMER tries to detect if candle has a short real body. And it's definition [is hardcoded](https://github.com/trufanov-nok/ta-lib-rt/blob/master/ta-lib-rt/c/src/ta_common/ta_global.c#L149) to `real body is short when it's shorter than the average of the 10 previous candles' real bodies`. So it can't detect anything in first 10 rows and by skipping rows you move the row you are interested in too close to the beginning of the dataset.

Comment: Based on this limitation, we have to identify the pattern ourselves