# TaLib is detecting wrong hammer candles?

Tags: python, ta-lib, technical-indicator

I am using both **TaLib** and Candlesticks first time and started off by writing code detecting candlestick. I am using CCXT to fetch data of [Binance USDT for 1 hour](https://www.binance.com/en/trade/BTC_USDT).

It is detecting hammers on the following timestamp:

```
ts
2021-10-15 19:00:00+00:00    100
2021-10-16 20:00:00+00:00    100
2021-10-17 12:00:00+00:00    100
```

Based on my understanding, the hammer candle is bullish/green but when I look at the chart on the given timestamp I found it red. What am I doing wrong? All timestamps are in UTC. The code is given below:

```
import pandas as pd
import ccxt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import talib


def gen_ts_text(ts):
    timestamp = ts / 1000
    dt_object = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
    # print(dt_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    return dt_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


def get_data(pair, duration):
    exchange = ccxt.binance()
    # A week old data
    ohlcv = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(pair, timeframe=duration, limit=100)
    df = pd.DataFrame(ohlcv, columns=['ts', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
    df['ts'] = df['ts'].apply(gen_ts_text)
    df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts']).dt.tz_localize('UTC')
    df.set_index("ts", inplace=True)
    return df


def hammer(open, high, low, close):
    result = talib.CDLHAMMER(open, high, low, close)
    return result
```

**main.py**

```
from ta_functions import *

# https://www.binance.com/en/trade/BTC_USDT
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = get_data('BTC/USDT', '1h')
    print('-------------------------------------------')
    hammer_pattern = hammer(data['open'], data['high'], data['low'], data['close'])
    # hanging_pattern = hangging_man(data['open'], data['high'], data['low'], data['close'])

    data['hammer'] = hammer_pattern
    # data['hanging_man'] = hanging_pattern
    print('HAMMER ......')
    print(data['hammer'][data['hammer'] > 0])
    print(len(data['hammer'][data['hammer'] > 0]))
```

[image]

Comment: @Python Analyst has a great answer to this. Another thing to consider that I am sure you are aware of is the difficulty of working with different kinds of time zones in your data. I had a similar problem to this. Remember to change time zone on Binance to match your time zone in your datasets. Oh yeah, and you should definitely consider downloading full datasets in csv from Binance as CCXT can only fetch 1500 candles at a time. I use this with a script to concat all of them together in one massive dataset. Happy trading :)

Comment: @PaulBrink TZ is in UTC

Answer (score 4):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/65978978/13703615, @Ran A has mentioned about the limitation based on the methodology of TaLib package, leading to a 'wrong' hammer candlestick detection.

Here is my customized function to identify a hammer candlestick, regardless whether it is at the low level or high level:

```
import numpy as np
import decimal

def pattern_hammer(df: pd.DataFrame()):
    """
    Expected df contains Open, High, Low, Close,
    """
    # Compute percentile
    for level in [50, 90]:
        df[f'{level}_percentile'] = df[['high', 'low']].apply(lambda x: np.percentile(x, q=decimal.Decimal(level)),
                                                              axis=1)

    condition = ((df['open'].values >= df['50_percentile'].values)  # open larger then 50 percentile, i.e. at the upper half
                 & (df['close'].values >= df['90_percentile'].values)  # close larger then 90 percentile, i.e. at the top of candlestick
                 & (df['close'].values >= df['open'].values)  # bullish candlestick
                 )

    df['hammer'] = np.where(condition, 1, 0)
    return df
```

The definition of hammer pattern varies among all users, it is better if your could define yours before calculation. It is possible to add criteria that could help you identify the pattern.

Hope it could drive you to the ultimate solution!

Comment: Did you use a package for decimal? Im getting "decimal" is not defined

Comment: @PaulBrink Definitely, for financial application, it is a common practice to use decimal for high precision in calculation, but in return of longer computation time. I have edited my answer by import `decimal` package. 

If you want to use float for computation, then simply use `np.percentile(x, q=level)` instead of `np.percentile(x, q=decimal.Decimal(level))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't check is it working correctly, but pattern "hammer" or "inverse hummer" can be both green and red